# JavaScript, Function to obtain Array of an Array with the desired sum of its values. Combinatorial

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinatorics

I would like a function in JavaScript, where I can obtain an array with the corresponding positions of an Array of numbers, where adding their values ​​results in the number that I want to obtain.

New.
I need return only one response, although there are other possible ones.
Although the ideal answer is the longest array.

**Example 1:**

I have the Array with the following numbers:

```
[9,4,11,6,3,5,7]
```

I want to obtain an array where the sum of its values ​​gives me the value 7

Desired response: `[1,4]`

**Example 2:**

With the same starting array as Example 1, I want to obtain the value 14

Desired response: `[1,4,6]`

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Por favor, puede escribir la pregunta en Inglés? (Please may you write the question in English?)

Comment: Given that there are multiple possible solutions (eg Example 1 could return `[6]` and Example 2 could return `[2,4]`) how do you want to decide which possible solution to return?

Comment: You're right Jamiec. But it must return only one, although there are other possible ones.